# Is there a unique cyclic submodule for every factor dividing the order of a cyclic module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $\langle v\rangle$ is a cyclic module over a PID of order $a$. Then there is a cyclic submodule of order $b$ for any  $b$ dividing $a$. Namely, $\langle cv\rangle$, where $c$ is such that $bc=a$ in $R$.

I know that a finite cyclic group has a *unique* cyclic subgroup for each divisor of the order of the group. For cyclic modules over a PID, is it still true that a cyclic submodule of order dividing the order of the given module is also unique? If so, why?

Any submodule of $\langle v\rangle$ necessarily has form $\langle rv\rangle$ for some $r\in R$. If $\langle cv\rangle$ and $\langle rv\rangle$ both have order $b$, then it follows that
$$
b=\frac{a}{\gcd(c,a)}=\frac{a}{\gcd(r,a)}
$$
so $\gcd(c,a)=\gcd(r,a)$ but I can't tell if $\langle cv\rangle=\langle rv\rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\langle cv\rangle$ and $\langle rv\rangle$ both have order $b$. Let $d=\gcd(c,a)=\gcd(r,a)$. By Bezout's identity, there exist $s,t\in R$ such that $sc+ta=d$, or $sc/d+ta/d=1$. Then
$$
rv=\left(\frac{sc}{d}+\frac{ta}{d}\right)rv=\frac{rscv}{d}+tbrv=\frac{rs}{d}cv\in\langle cv\rangle.
$$
So $\langle rv\rangle\subseteq\langle cv\rangle$. By symmetry, $\langle rv\rangle=\langle cv\rangle$, so such a submodule is indeed unique.

Comment: In the OP, how to see $b=\frac{a}{\gcd(r,a)}$?

Comment: @Arrow It can be found as part 3) of Theorem 6.2 of Steven Roman's _Advanced Linear Algebra_. At the time of writing this, this [link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F0-387-27474-X_7) has a preview.

Comment: Dear Ben, I saw that proof a couple of hours ago, thanks! By the way, I recommend the proof in Theorem 6.3 of the third edition - it's neater!

Comment: Dear @Arrow, Ah good, I'm glad. Your comment sparked my curiosity, so I had to check it out and I agree, the argument there is much nicer!